# Converting form data to an object

Tags: javascript

I don't want to post the data to a server I want to pass it into a client side function that takes an object. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Can you elaborate / add some context?

Comment: Have a look at this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/serialize-form-to-json-with-jquery

Comment: *"I want to pass it into a client side function that takes a json object."* I'll give you 10:1 odds that you don't, that instead you want to pass it to a client-side function that accepts a **JavaScript** object. JSON is purely a textual notation; by the time you're actually interacting with things, they're JavaScript objects, nothing whatsoever to do with JSON. Now, if your client-side function accepts a string and expects that string to contain JSON-encoded data that it will deserialize and process, then apologies. :-) But I suspect not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using [jQuery](http://jquery.com) you may want to look at the [.serializeArray()](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray) function it provides as it does all you want in a single call. Using [TJ's example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359587/converting-form-data-to-an-object/7359632#7359632);

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('form[name="f1"]').submit(function() {
            var person = $(this).serializeArray();
            // Do what you will with 'person' now...
        });
    });
</script>
<form name="f1">
    <input type="text" name="firstname" />
    <input type="text" name="lastname" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

This way you don't have to manually build an object and declare a property for each field which helps avoid human error.

If for some reason you don't want to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com) then you could always [look at the code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.6.3/src/ajax.js) to see the logic used and create your own function.

Comment: hrrm, this doesn't work perfectly. It results in this string `email=test%40example.com&password=1234` my goal is to have `{email:'test@example.com', password: '1234'}` @Alasdair

Comment: @fancy Oops! I used the wrong function by accident. Please see the changes I've made to my answer. Basically, use `.serializeArray()` instead of `.serialize()`. This will provide an array containing an object with a `name` and `value` property for each field. If you want a single object with name/value mapping (which is likely) you may wish to create an additional function: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/serialize-form-to-json-with-jquery/1186309#1186309

Answer (score 6):

You can just create your own object as such:

```
<form name='f1'>

<input type='text' name='firstname' />
<input type='text' name='lastname' />

</form>

window.onload = function()
{
    var Person = 
    {  
      'FirstName' : document.f1.firstname.value, 
      'LastName' : document.f1.lastname.value 
    }
}
```

A `JSON object` is just a regular Javascript object, because JSON is subset of Javascript.

Comment: +1 Specifically, there ***are no*** "JSON objects". There are merely JSON representations of objects. This has nothing whatsoever to do with JSON.

Comment: @TJ couldnt be more true, and nice initial you got there ;)

Comment: `@TJHeuvel:` Yeah, you too. :-)

Answer (score 0):

your question is the first on google, so here. Looks like the first way is the least amount of code.

```js
var form = document.getElementById('iLoveLucy')

var obj1 = [...form.elements].reduce((_, el) => (_[el.name] = el.value, _), {})
console.log(obj1)

// another way
var obj2 = Object.assign({},
  ...[...form.elements].map(({name,value}) => ({[name]: value}))
)
console.log(obj2)

// a third way
var obj3 = new class {
  constructor() {
    [...form.elements].map(({name,value}) => this[name] = value)
  }
}
console.log(obj3)
```

```html
<form id="iLoveLucy">
  <input name="fred" value="grumpy"/>
  <input name="wilma" value="tired"/>
  <input name="lucy" value="foolish"/>
  <input name="ricky" value="upset"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Any [`FormData` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest_API/Using_FormData_Objects) can be converted into a plain JS object using the [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) static method. Using both together looks like:

```js
const form = document.getElementById('fooform');
const formData = new FormData(form);
const data = Object.fromEntries(formData);
console.log('form data as object', data);
```

```html
<form id="fooform" method="post">
  <p>
    <label>Your email address:
      <input
        name="email"
        placeholder="email"
        required
        type="email"
        value="example@foo.bar" />
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Your phone number:
      <input
        name="phone"
        placeholder="phone number"
        required
        type="tel"
        value="(123) 456-7890" />
    </label>
  </p>
</form>
```